# get simple data like string in viewcomponent in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Hi I have a viewcomponet that read text from a txt file and i want to show that text in viewcomponent
this is my ViewComponents ".cs"

```
public class MainFooterViewComponent:ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        string lastUpdateTime = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./last.txt");

        return View(last);
    }
}
```

And in ".cshtml" i want to show "last"

```
 <li>last" @last</li>
```

How can I do that in simple way

Answer (score 0):

hhe common way  to use view components

Inside of Shared folder you have to crate a Components folder and then MainFooter folder. Create the partial view MainFooter.cshtml there

```
@model string

<div>

    <p>@Model</p>
</div>
```

Create class in a Controllers folder

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "MainFooter")]
public class MainFooterViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
 string lastUpdateTime = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./last.txt");

return View("MainFooter", lastUpdateTime );
}
```

Layout or main view

```
<div> @(await Component.InvokeAsync("MainFooter")) </div>
```

Comment: I think  it would be `lastUpdateTime` instead of that `last` in `View("MainFooter", lastUpdateTime)`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thanks, it was a typo in OP question, I just copied it without reading

Comment: Yes, it was typo I got it therefore, just point you out.

Comment: I tested this metod and return   "The view 'Components/MainFooter/"1401/01/23"' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Pages/Components/MainFooter/"1401/01/23".cshtml"

Comment: Also use with "return View("MainFooter",lastUpdateTime);" I got this error "The view 'Components/MainFooter/MainFooter' was not found." Although  I have Mainfooter in shared folder

Comment: @sunny In my answer it is written that you have to  place MainFooter view  in Views/Shared/Componets/MainFooter folder, not in Shared and I don' t know why did you create 1401/01/23 view